# Google webmasters detects Vue.js Website spam content Injection

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-search-console

This question is related to Google webmasters and its platform is Vue.js website. "Google has detected harmful content on some of your site’s pages. We recommend that you remove it as soon as possible. Until then, browsers such as Google Chrome will display a warning when users visit or download certain files from your site."[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9Jkg.png)

Is there anything we need to know about it and can perform checks to find what's wrong.

Comment: Check if you have v-html instead of v-text or {{{ }}} instead of {{ }}. These directives with content created by users can lead to content injection.

Comment: @Daniel Yes we have them and we need them. So our content team can include links and shortcodes inside content sections. This recommendation is for websites with user-generated content. Our content is created by trusted authors, so we don't need to validate it.

Comment: You have some possibilities: 1. contact with the google support team and explain it to them. 2. change source code to eliminate v-html and {{{ }}}. 3 use server-side rendering tools like nuxt.

Comment: @Daniel We are using Nuxt.js.

Comment: but probably with Hydration, did you tried generating static sites. You can read more in https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/hydration.html and https://nuxtjs.org/guides/concepts/server-side-rendering/ the problem with nuxt ssr is that it render on bacned and allow to rerender on frontend with the same insecure v-html and {{{ }}}.